# List/Library item full Url in Powershell

Tags: 2010, list, powershell, document-library

I have a script going through all Web.Lists and List.Items in given site collection. On one point i want to have a full link to the item that is being processed. I'm doing it this way:

```
$ItemURL = $List.ParentWeb.Url + "/" + $List.RootFolder.Url + "/dispform.aspx?id=" + $Item.Id
```

It works on all lists, but not on libraries due to lacking /Forms/ after library name. Any idea how can i modify it to work also on libraries? Adding "/Forms/" strictly to the line of code will break link for lists.

Comment: `string itemUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}?ID={2}", properties.Web.Url, properties.List.Forms[PAGETYPE.PAGE_DISPLAYFORM].Url, properties.ListItem.ID);` convert this to powershell

Comment: OR `var fullUrl = item.ParentList.ParentWeb.Site.MakeFullUrl(item.ParentList.DefaultDisplayFormUrl) + "?ID=" + item.ID;` convert this to powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for base type of the list type and handle it accordingly. If the base type is "DocumentLibrary" the you can have item url adding "Forms/" and else will be your list item url like below

```
if($List.BaseTemplate -eq "DocumentLibrary"){
 $ItemURL = $List.ParentWeb.Url + "/" + $List.RootFolder.Url + "/Forms/dispform.aspx?id=" + $Item.Id
}else{
 $ItemURL = $List.ParentWeb.Url + "/" + $List.RootFolder.Url + "/dispform.aspx?id=" + $Item.Id
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Try with List TemplateID

https://fcsharepoint.com/2015/08/19/sharepoint-2013-base-types-list-template-and-definition-ids-and-content-types-ids/

```
   if($List.TemplateID -eq "101"){
    $ItemURL = $List.ParentWeb.Url + "/" + $List.RootFolder.Url + "/Forms/dispform.aspx?id=" + $Item.Id
    }
    else{
    $ItemURL = $List.ParentWeb.Url + "/" + $List.RootFolder.Url + "/dispform.aspx?id=" + $Item.Id
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [SPList.DefaultDisplayFormUr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.defaultdisplayformurl(v=office.14).aspx) instead of assuming that it's /(Forms/)?displayform.aspx